# How to test if React renders button when state is not empty array

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component which has multiple useState calls. It renders button when one of the state is populated. How can I mock populated state to be able to test if the button is rendered?

```
const Component = () => {
  
  const [csvData, setCsvData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  const handleCSVLoad = (data) => {
    // ...some logic to process the data
    setCsvData(data)
  }
  // ...other functions

  return(
    <>
     // ...some other components
     <CSVReader
        onFileLoaded={handleCSVLoad}
     />
     csvData[0]&& <button data-testId='submit_button'>Submit</button>
    </>

  )
```

the csvData is populated when CSV data is loaded with react-csv-reader.
I want to be able to write test like that:

```
it('does render Submit button', () => {
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<Component />);
    const submitButton = queryByTestId('submit_button');
    expect(submitButton).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I tried to mock useState like this:

```
import React, { useState as useStateMock } from 'react';

jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useState: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('testing useState mocked', () => {
  const setState = jest.fn();
  const useStateMock = () => [[{email: 'test@test.com'}], setState];

  jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(useStateMock);

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
});
```

but it breaks as errors state is now defined and submit button is not rendered when error is not an empty array.